# How would one calculate a limit as it approaches infinity or 0?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion, calculus

In my spare time I like to program theorems.

```js
const PI = 3.141592653589793; // Math.PI
function CalculatePi(total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) {
  if (addSubBool) {
    total -= (4 / x)
    console.log(`${total}\tDifference: ${PI - total}`);
  } else {
    total += (4 / x)
    console.log(`${total}\tDifference: ${total - PI}`);
  }
  if (total !== PI) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      CalculatePi(total, x + 2, !addSubBool);
    }, 100);
  }
}
CalculatePi();
```

This one is a recursive call to calculate pi. I based it off [this link](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/pi/glseries.html)

My question is, how do I calculate a limit in programming? This call will go to infinity.

So how does a calculator or other programming languages calculate a limit as x approaches infinity? Would I set a maximum for x?

Comment: Do you want to limit number of calculations or a stop at a result that is close enough for your needs

Comment: The latter. If there is a way to optimize the amount of computations, I would be interested to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below we use `loop` and `recur` to allow your function to infinitely recur. And instead of using `setTimeout`, I'm recurring as fast as possible but instead outputting a result for every interval of 1000 `x` -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const calculatePi = (limit = Infinity) =>
  loop // loop our function ...
    ( (total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) =>
      { if (x > limit) // stop condition
          return total
          
        if (x % 1e3 === 1) // display progress as we go
          console.log(x, total, total - Math.PI)

        if (total === Math.PI) // solution found
          return total
        
        if (addSubBool)
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total - 4 / x  // next total
            , x + 2          // next x
            , false          // next addSubBool
            )

        else
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total + 4 / x  // next total
            , x + 2          // next x
            , true           // next addSubBool
            )
     }
   )
   
console.log(calculatePi(1e7))
```

As you can see this method takes a long time to converge on the answer. Even after ten million (10M) x, we still have only calculated 6 points of precision -

```
x       total               diff
...
9997001 3.1415924535297624 -2.0006003076389334e-7
9998001 3.1415924535497695 -2.0004002365681117e-7
9999001 3.141592453569776 -2.0002001699381822e-7
```

A different approach will take `precision` as an input of `calculatePi`. Instead of limiting by some arbitrary `x`, we will continue computing until a specific precision is reached. For demo purposes, this function also returns `x` so we can see how big `x` had to get before the desired precision was reached -

```
const calculatePi = (precision = 1e5) =>
  loop
    ( (total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) =>
      { if (total * precision >> 0 === Math.PI * precision >> 0)
          return [ total, x ]

        if (addSubBool)
          return recur
            ( total - 4 / x
            , x + 2
            , false
            )

        else
          return recur
            ( total + 4 / x
            , x + 2
            , true
            )
     }
   )
```

As you can see, `x` goes beyond 37 million to reach 7 decimals of precision -

```
console .log
  ( calculatePi (1e2)
    // [ 3.14999586659347, 239 ]

  , calculatePi (1e3)
    // [ 3.141000236580159, 3377 ]

  , calculatePi (1e4)
    // [ 3.1415000095284658, 21589 ]

  , calculatePi (1e5)
    // [ 3.141599999994786, 272243 ]

  , calculatePi (1e7)
    // [ 3.1415926000000005, 37320609 ]
  )
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const calculatePi = (precision = 1e5) =>
  loop
    ( (total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) =>
      { if (total * precision >> 0 === Math.PI * precision >> 0)
          return [ total, x ]
        
        if (addSubBool)
          return recur
            ( total - 4 / x
            , x + 2
            , false
            )

        else
          return recur
            ( total + 4 / x
            , x + 2
            , true
            )
     }
   )
   
console .log
  ( calculatePi (1e2)
    // [ 3.14999586659347, 239 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e3)
    // [ 3.141000236580159, 3377 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e4)
    // [ 3.1415000095284658, 21589 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e5)
    // [ 3.141599999994786, 272243 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e7)
    // [ 3.1415926000000005, 37320609 ]
  )
```

Finally, it doesn't make much sense to check against `Math.PI` when calculating pi; I imagine whole goal is to calculate a number we pretend not to know. To do that, we start with some `guess` and then measure the difference between it and the `total`. If the guess is within the specified tolerance, return the guess -

```
const calculatePi = (precision = 1e5) =>
  loop
    // guess starts at 1
    ( (guess = 1, total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) =>
      { if (Math .abs (guess - total) * precision < 1)
          return [ guess, x ]

        if (addSubBool)
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total          // next guess
            , total - 4 / x  // next total
            , x + 2          // next x
            , false          // next addSubBool
            )

        else
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total         // next guess
            , total + 4 / x // next total
            , x + 2         // next x
            , true          // next addSubBool
            )
     }
   )
```

We can see it works as intended. Admittedly, I'm surprised by the correlation between input precision and the necessary `x` to compute it -

```
console .log
  ( calculatePi (1e2)
    // [ 3.136592684838816, 403 ]

  , calculatePi (1e3)
    // [ 3.1410926536210413, 4003 ]

  , calculatePi (1e4)
    // [ 3.1415426535898248, 40003 ]

  , calculatePi (1e5)
    // [ 3.1415876535897618, 400003 ]

  , calculatePi (1e7)
    // [ 3.141592603589817, 40000003 ]
  )
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })
  
const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const calculatePi = (precision = 1e5) =>
  loop
    // guess starts at 1
    ( (guess = 1, total = 0, x = 1, addSubBool = false) =>
      { if (Math .abs (guess - total) * precision < 1)
          return [ guess, x ]
        
        if (addSubBool)
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total          // next guess
            , total - 4 / x  // next total
            , x + 2          // next x
            , false          // next addSubBool
            )

        else
          return recur // recur with ...
            ( total         // next guess
            , total + 4 / x // next total
            , x + 2         // next x
            , true          // next addSubBool
            )
     }
   )
   
console .log
  ( calculatePi (1e2)
    // [ 3.136592684838816, 403 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e3)
    // [ 3.1410926536210413, 4003 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e4)
    // [ 3.1415426535898248, 40003 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e5)
    // [ 3.1415876535897618, 400003 ]
  
  , calculatePi (1e7)
    // [ 3.141592603589817, 40000003 ]
  )
```

Comment: This is a very well written explanation. I could not have asked for a better one. I am glad you were able to be surprised in the end by the input precision with the necessary x to compute it. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm very happy to help. I have [more answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+loop+recur) using `loop` and `recur` if you'd like to see them in used in other contexts :D

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would define a suitable tolerance and then compare the difference between the current and last values. If the difference falls below the tolerance stop computing and you know your result is accurate to plus or minus your tolerance.

You could also keep computing until you get two values the same as that likely means you have reached the limit of precision for the datatype you're storing the result in and any further calculation is meaningless.